# Password is visible when i post the form in https with mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis, https

I have a website and i use self sign certificate .MVC ASP .when i submit my form to login  i can see my password in fiddler .why ?

[image]

Comment: Because you've configured Fiddler to act as a man in the middle TLS sniffer? Remember when you trusted Fiddler's root cert? The one called "DO NOT TRUST".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddler is doing a man in the middle scenario to snoop the traffic and fiddler can do this when you enable "decrpt https traffic in fiddler options" .

For more details 
https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp